# Foreach $item is not displaying

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

Having trouble using foreach to output the contents of a mysql table. The table (tr, td) etc is being printed out for each entry in the mysql table, but there is nothing between the td and /td tags, where each $item should be echoed.

```
$sql = 'SELECT domain FROM domainsuggestions'; 
$domains = mysqli_query($link, $sql);  // get domain suggestions from table
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Domain Suggestions</td>
    </tr>   
    <?php foreach ($domains as $item): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($item, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic for working with MySQL is quite off. You need to perform the query first, grab the resource ID of the results, and then loop through the results.

```
$sql = 'SELECT domain FROM domainsuggestions'; 
$results= mysqli_query($link, $sql);  // get domain suggestions from table
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Domain Suggestions</td>
    </tr>   
    <?php while ($item = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($item['domain '], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</table>
```

Comment: How can I accomplish this with the foreach?

Comment: @Nick `foreach` expects an *iterable* element. You don't have one, because you have not retrieved all the data from the database yet; you only get the data one row at a time by calling `mysqli_fetch_*`. Why does it need to be a `foreach`?

Comment: I'm working my way through the book "Build your own database driven website using PHP & MySQL - 4th edition" and this is how it is taught. I don't understand why it isn't working and I would like to before moving on as this usage is used and built upon in the coming chapters.

Answer (score 0):

`foreach` expects an *iterable* element, i.e. something that has many entries that it can *iterate* through. That's typically an array, but can also be an object that implements the `Iterable` interface.

What you get when running `mysqli_query` is a *resource*. That's just a handle on a MySQL result set. The data is not yet in PHP, MySQL just gave you a handle saying *"okay, I got the results for you ready, come get them whenever you need to"*. Calling `mysqli_fetch_assoc` gets one result row from MySQL. Calling it again gets the next, and the next and so on. This is not a process you can *iterate* through, you can just keep calling `mysqli_fetch_assoc` until there are no more results.

That's why `foreach` does not work.